# Play on Linux not showing League of Legends

Tags: 12.04, playonlinux

I am using the following:

`Ubuntu 12.04`
`PlayOnLinux 4.0.14` (henceforth referred to as `POL)

Installed `POL` today, trying to get League of Legends running.  Everything seems to install smoothly, but when I go to the `install` button in the GUI (as in running `POL`), League isn't listed. Not in testing or games, or in search.  I've hit refresh, rebooted.

Should I attempt to re-install `POL`?  Manually add league?  Anything would be helpful.

Comment: Give a try to `Wine`

Comment: @AdityaPatil Play on Linux is a Wine GUI if you will.

And I have bad experience making things work with wine in the past.

Comment: Fixing errors(or at least finding them) is easier in Wine(at least that's what I think)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `playonlinux` and then go install the latest version by hand from the website. I notice that the Ubuntu apt-get repo version is outdated.